# initiallize a DbContext in EF Core, null exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

Im trying create Asp.net core API. I have a problem with initialise dbcontext,
I'm trying this in the controller:

```
    private static DBModelContext _DbContext;
    public Program(DBModelContext dbContext)
    {
        _DbContext = dbContext;
    }
```

but I encounter null pointer exception. In debug, _DbContext and dbContext are both null. Why?

Comment: I think this is a problem with the wrong location of the code

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem and i solved this problem by sending the `dbContext` as a parameter into the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
private readonly DBModelContext _DbContext; //Try removing static
public Program(DBModelContext dbContext)
{
    _DbContext = dbContext;
}
```

Do you actually need a static instance?

Comment: I tried without a static phrase, but I did not see any difference

Comment: Wait, where are you trying to call the context?

Is it from the Model or from the Controller?